# Adding more content overflows into other div

Tags: html, css, overflow

firstly apologies for the extremely messy code you are about to see, still new to this game!

I would like each section to be the same size as the browser window, seems to be working fine at the moment. However I have just ran into a problem, when I add a certain amount of content, images or anything, the content overflows into the div above.

HTML

```
    <div class="header">
</div>
<div id="work">
    <div class="project clouds 1">
        <div class="center">
            <div class="icon"></div>
            <p class="pTitle">Title</p>
            <p class="pSub">Sub</p>
            <p class="pAbout">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.     Donec vel massa erat. Donec urna odio, pulvinar a cursus eu, lobortis non odio. Donec lorem sem, adipiscing vitae velit vel, vestibulum mattis nisi. Duis ullamcorper vitae dui vitae porta. Maecenas ultrices quam quam, eu tristique dolor placerat fermentum. Pellentesque cursus volutpat odio et aliquam. Proin erat felis, cursus sed ligula in, commodo gravida purus. Donec vestibulum purus a ante sagittis eleifend. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus tempor ultrices tellus, et tempus risus lobortis at. Nunc placerat elementum dui, id tincidunt ante pellentesque sit amet.

Phasellus ut accumsan ipsum, a bibendum ante. In in sagittis elit. Pellentesque et urna id metus fermentum convallis sodales ut velit. In vel blandit sapien, at mattis risus. Nunc eleifend nibh in massa vestibulum, vel mattis odio scelerisque. Praesent faucibus nibh a arcu suscipit, non pretium arcu venenatis. Sed ornare sit amet nisi in rhoncus. Phasellus et ligula ullamcorper, ullamcorper turpis rhoncus, elementum leo.

Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nullam semper mattis turpis, vel vulputate nibh ornare at. Mauris non tincidunt diam. Nulla arcu velit, rhoncus id nisi quis, posuere varius turpis. Sed ut leo tortor. Duis blandit, sapien quis laoreet suscipit, nibh felis scelerisque arcu, vitae convallis leo augue at leo. Proin eget neque rhoncus justo lobortis vehicula. Sed posuere tellus porttitor diam congue, ut imperdiet libero egestas. Aliquam pulvinar ligula ac erat suscipit tempus. Sed sed lacus vitae orci porttitor fringilla nec id tortor. Mauris sapien lorem, pretium eu turpis sed, luctus interdum augue. Fusce sed ligula sollicitudin, gravida libero vitae, ultricies nunc. Ut rhoncus tortor id laoreet tincidunt. Etiam pulvinar enim id purus convallis dictum. Donec suscipit lectus in adipiscing fermentum. Curabitur cursus commodo mauris vel imperdiet.</p>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="project ice 2">
    <div class="center">
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <p class="pTitle">Title</p>
        <p class="pSub">Sub</p>
        <p class="pAbout">About</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
width:100%;
margin:0 auto;
}

.header {
height:100vh;
background-color:#2c3e50;
width:100%;
color:#fff;
font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight:300;
font-size:1.7em;
}

.header .alignRight {
text-align:right;
position:relative;
top:45%;
transform:translate(0,-50%);
-webkit-transform:translate(0,-50%);
-moz-transform:translate(0,-50%);
-o-transform:translate(0,-50%);
-ms-transform:translate(0,-50%);
width:500px;
margin:0 auto;
}

.header .alignRight span {
font-weight:400;
}

.viewWork {
margin-top:15px;
}

.viewWork a {
text-transform:capitalize;
font-size:.6em;
text-decoration:none;
color:rgba(255,255,255,.4);
border-top:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.0);
border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.0);
-webkit-transition:.5s;
transition:.5s;
padding:4px;
}

.viewWork a:hover {
color:#fff;
border-color:#fff;
}

/* End Header/Section 1 */
/* Start Portfolio/Section2 */


.project {
height:100vh;
background-color:#2c3e50;
width:100%;
color:#1c1c1c;
font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight:300;
font-size:1em;
}

.project .center {
text-align:center;
position:relative;
top:5rem;
transform:translate(0,-20%);
-webkit-transform:translate(0,-20%);
-moz-transform:translate(0,-20%);
-o-transform:translate(0,-20%);
-ms-transform:translate(0,-20%);
width:800px;
margin:0 auto;
}

.project .center span {
font-weight:400;
}

.icon {
margin:0 auto;
background-color:red;
width: 40px;
height:40px;
}

.clouds {
background-color:#f2f2f2;
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
border-bottom:1px solid #d6d6d6;
}

.ice {
background-color:#fff;
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
border-bottom:1px solid #d6d6d6;
}

.project .center p{
margin:0;
padding-top:12px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6G5gK/)

Again, sorry for the messy code, but I'm sure you can see my problem. I'd like the same distance from the top of each section. Thanks :)

Comment: What do you want it to do? To increase the `height` of each section? So they are bigger than screen size? or do you want to create scrollable inside of each section?

Comment: Basically I want to add content to each section, but as you can see the second section is overflowing into the first. If that makes sense? I want it looking like the third one is at the moment. Whenever I add content, it seems to mess up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove these styles from `.project .center {`:

```
transform:translate(0,-20%);
-webkit-transform:translate(0,-20%);
-moz-transform:translate(0,-20%);
-o-transform:translate(0,-20%);
-ms-transform:translate(0,-20%);
```

See **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6G5gK/1/)**